# TeamCity: How to include referenced project outside the .Net solution folder

Tags: asp.net, teamcity

I am new to TeamCity so please bear with me. I have the following project structure in SVN [(SVN Structure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnyUm.png). Libraries folder is a .Net solution which includes several projects. Solution 1, 2 and 3 reference some of the projects from the Libraries solution. I created a project in TeamCity for "Solution 1". I added a first step with runner type: Visual Studio (sln). In the build configuration I pointed at the SVN folder with the "Solution 1" sln file. When I tried to run the build if failed. TeamCity could not compile the code as it could not find the referencing projects which are in the Libraries folder.

When I move the Libraries into the Solution 1 folder, the build worked. However I do not want to move the Libraries into a specific solution as most of the Solutions reference some of the projects in the Libraries.

Is there anyway to reference projects which are outside the solution folder?

I am not interested in referencing dll files or excutable as the Library solution changes quite often. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221340/how-to-include-dependencies-outside-solution-directory-in-net-project-for-teamc)

Comment: Could you show us your VCS configuration from TeamCity? Does it include all your folders: both Libraries and Project 1 to 3?

Comment: No, it includes just solution 1 folder, I have been just just adding another VCS root pointing at the Libraries folder. I have not tested if it works yet.

Comment: Hi Peska, thank you for your comment it helped me to figure out how to do it.